Interacting with Secure Browser pop up in Playwright
I'm trying to automate with Playwright an e-commerce checkout scenario using Paypal as a payment option selection. Upon selecting the Paypal button, a secure browser pops up that asks for credentials to see the account bank/credit/ etc information for purchase.
I don't understand how to get Playwright to "switch" to the secure browser that pops up to interact with it. This browser is detached from the original and has its own dev tools.
Any guidance would be greatly helpful!
I've tried:
const newPagePromise = context.waitForEvent('page');
await page.locator('.mt-4 > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div').click(); //what triggers the new page window 
const newPage = await newPagePromise;
await newPage.waitForLoadState()
newPage.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Pay with PayPal' }).isEnabled();`

but that newPage const isn't getting attached to the new page in order to be able to interact with it
in my UI view the two staggered pages look like this:
(https://i.sstatic.net/GaFVE.png)
I've also tried waiting for a popup but that doesnt work either since I guess its not a true pop up. It's a separate window that appears.

Please share a complete, runnable [mcve] of your code. Thanks. newPage.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Pay with PayPal' }).isEnabled(); looks like it's missing await, for starters.

this actually was the problem, how silly. thank you!
